# Book series about a boy who runs away from his walled city and finds his sister in a hidden city in the wasteland outside

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't for the life of me remember the book series. A boy and his brother live with their father in a world where there are clusters of cities and everyone outside of them lives in poverty and disease. He eventually meets his sister and he joins the circus act in it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking of [Pure](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9680114-pure) by Julianna Baggott?  But there isn't a circus, and I'm pretty sure you would remember a dome instead of clusters of cities.

Comment: No I`m sorry thats not it, his brother joins their worlds version of the army and eventually destroys the city at the end of the first book, the cover was a triangle with swirls at each point.